# Spring boot : Sometimes not getting any Reponse from Rest Api based service

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, jar

I have a few rest API-based jar services that are deployed in the Linux CentOS server. Everything is working fine but sometimes I am observing that I am not getting API responses from the service. it's a rare case and after a long time run, it's causing the issue. I have already checked a few blogs and posts but not getting the expected solution.

**I have tried in several ways:**

- From front-end application
- From postman
- Using curl
- Tried with telnet -it's connected and the port is also open
- Checked jar is running or not - it's running in the defined port.
- Network connectivity - is also ok.
- Created some sample endpoint without using DB call to check the problem.
- Put some logging in the code to highlight in and out times.
- Make some static API calling from the same machine as well as different machines.

*But still the same problem. No response from any endpoint.*

I have checked the log files, everything is normal, and no new log append in the files.

***But when I restart the jar (kill the port and run again) then it's going to normal and works fine.***

I am not sure what's causing this. Anyone facing this same problem?
What is the possible reason that can freeze the responses?
Need help to resolve the issues or any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Is it a one-time occurrence for a single request? Or does it then not respond to any more requests?

Comment: it's not one time, multiple times. but sometimes in any request

Comment: This reads like the JVM got stuck somehow, e.g. it might be desparate for some more memory but because it can't free enough the garbage collector might be running on steroids without success and you might have gotten an OOM error eventually. This is just a guess though and hard to diagnose remotely, especially without more info. What you should do is look for patterns like: Which endpoints are affected? What happens before this starts? Might there be something that's recurring every time? Are you able to grab a thread or heap dump and if so what to they tell you?

Comment: Can you upload your project to GitHub and post the link in a comment here

Comment: @Thomas, Thanks for your suggestion. I have checked in several times and it's a rare case situation. When the issue occurs there is no response from any endpoint. when it occurred nothing happen before. I checked and there is no error or warning in the logs append. everything is normal in the logs, only new logs are not appended as the service is not responding or processing any request. 
Even for the checking, I have run the jar separately and there is no incoming request happened, only postman manual request is allowed. but after a few days, I observed postman request is also not responding

Comment: @ArthurKlezovich, Sorry man, I can not share the code as it's a client production-level project :(.

Comment: So even if there's nothing happening at all the system stops accepting requests? Did you check whether it could actually be any application running in between e.g. a webserver, proxy etc.? Of if there's nothing in the app, does anything run scheduled which might open connections and not close them or eat up your memory?

Comment: @Thomas, There is no scheduler or proxy added in that service.

Answer (score 0):

I think its occure when number of request is large or your system hang out
The way to prevent this from happening is to set timeOut for a request that If there is no response after a certain time, the message will be send
and maybe its occure when The number of messages is large so is better to use io.github.resilience4j.ratelimiter to handle it.
good luck

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. it's a rare case situation. 
For the checking purpose, I have run the jar separately and there is no incoming request allowed, only postman manual request is allowed. it's worked fine in the beginning. but after a few days, I make another request and it does not respond.

Comment: do you try repeat request for Specified time  and check it , maybe you should write health check for your API

Comment: Spring Actuator has already been implemented and the same problem.